# How can i fix this error with System.Math.Min

Tags: c#

I have this code, but show me a error with `System.Math.Min`. It shows it to me where is the bold: return System.Math.Min(System.Math.**Min**(dist(.

The error is:

```
byte Math.Min(byte val1, byte val2) (+ 10 overloads)
Returns the smaller of two 8-bit unsigned integers.
Return
Parameter val1 or val2, whichever is smaller.
```

Someone who can explain to me and how I can fix it.

The complete code is:

```
static int dist(string word1, int m, string word2, int n)
{
   
    int cost;

    if( m == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (n == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    if (word1[m-1] == word2[n - 1])
    {
        cost = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cost = 1;
    }
    

    return System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(dist(
        word1, m, word2, n - 1) + 1),
        dist(word1, m, word2, n-1),
        dist(word1, m - 1, word2, n - 1) + cost);


}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string word1 = "open", word2 = "peon";
    int m = word1.Length;
    int n = word2.Length;

    

    Console.WriteLine("The Levenshtein distance is " +
            dist(word1, m, word2, n));

}
```

Comment: First looks, that implementation doesn't look like the Levenshtein Distance Algorithm. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Codexer, the error in Min(dist(.  = byte Math.Min(byte val1, byte val2) (+ 10 overloads)
Returns the smaller of two 8-bit unsigned integers.
Return
Parameter val1 or val2, whichever is smaller.